# Spliting Varchar Fields With CRLF + Inserting Into New Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, newline, common-table-expression

I have a varchar column that consists of various text separated by CRLF. I need to split this column, each section running up until the next CRLF. These substrings then need to be inserted as new rows into a new table (which I have already created). The table with the varchar column is tblJobsTest and the column is called Notes. The new table is tblJobAppointmentNotes and consists of JobID and AppointmentNote.

Here is what I have so far....

```
DECLARE @crlf CHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR (10)
DECLARE @Note VARCHAR(MAX) = null

WHILE (SELECT LEN(Notes) FROM tblJobsTest) > 0
BEGIN
IF CHARINDEX(@crlf,Notes) > 0
    BEGIN
    SET @Note = SUBSTRING(Notes, 0, CHARINDEX(@crlf,Notes))
    INSERT INTO tblJobAppointmentNotes (AppointmentNote)
    VALUES (@Note)

    Update tblJAN
    SET tblJAN.JobID = tblJT.JobID
    From tblJobAppointmentNotes tblJAN
    INNER JOIN tblJobsTest tblJT ON tblJAN.JobID = tblJT.JobID

    UPDATE tblJobsTest
    SET Notes= SUBSTRING(Notes, LEN(@Note) + 1, LEN(Notes))
    END
ELSE
    INSERT INTO tblJobAppointmentNotes (JobID, AppointmentNote)
    SELECT JobID, Notes FROM tblJobsTest
END
```

The problem I am having is the column Name 'Notes' is not identified. The CHARINDEX can't look up a column I am guessing so I presume I need to use some form of CTE so this code can refer to each row in tblJobsTest?

Does anybody have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: what you expect from the statement `SELECT LEN(Notes) FROM tblJobsTest` read as the condition of the `WHILE` loop? the actual meaning is: 'take the length of the content of the field `Notes`, from table `tblJobsTest`, chosing a random row'. it is an odd check indeed...

Comment: Do this set-based using a string splitting function, not using while loops and charindex. See some examples here: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: Thanks :). Paolo that is the issue I am having. The column name notes is ambiguous at the minute and I want to alter this code so the while statement selects each row and runs the code based on the length of the varchar.

Comment: Cheers Aaron, not sure I am good enough to work out all that info but I will do my best. Just out of interest...why not a loop method with CHARINDEX? Can it not be done or just process intensive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are... Paste this into an empty query window and execute. Adapt to your needs...

EDIT: The same process, but set based approach to do this in one go for a whole table...

```
DECLARE @TableWithLongText TABLE(ID INT, LongText VARCHAR(MAX));
DECLARE @TableToInsertParts TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, TWLT_ID INT,PartNr INT, eachLine VARCHAR(MAX));


INSERT INTO @TableWithLongText VALUES
 (1,'This' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'is the text for ID=1' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'with' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + '4 lines')
,(2,'This' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'is the text for ID=2' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'with 3 lines');

WITH Recoded(ID,x) AS
(
    SELECT ID 
          ,CAST('<root><r>' +  REPLACE(twlt.LongText,CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'</r><r>') + '</r></root>' AS XML)
    FROM @TableWithLongText AS twlt
)
INSERT INTO @TableToInsertParts(TWLT_ID,PartNr,eachLine)
SELECT ID
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID)
      ,a.b.value('.','varchar(max)')
FROM Recoded
CROSS APPLY Recoded.x.nodes('/root/r') a(b);

SELECT * FROM @TableToInsertParts;
```

Comment: Thanks Shnugo! This works great but it doesn't solve my main problem. I originally had another variable in place of the column field 'Notes' called @Mystring and I could pass the data from each row through that variable and achieve the same results that your method does. The issue I am having is that with near 300,000 records I can't really parse each row individually! Is there any way of automatically setting the variable to the first row of data...running the code...and then using the second row of data and so on? So I effectively click execute and the code runs for each record on my table?

Comment: @Brett: I edited my example to show you, how you can do this for a whole table in one go, set based, no WHILE or CURSOR or stuff like this...

Comment: @Brett, did you check my last edit? Does it work for you? If yes, please vote up and/or mark as accepted, thx. If notm just come back with more information.

Comment: Thanks for this. Only just had a chance to try it and yes it works great.